# Kotlin hard-failing an up-cast to an inferred (in-site) parameter

Tags: kotlin

I am not sure if 'hard-failing' is the right word, but here is the problem I am facing. And it's taken me quite some time to reproduce this to the smallest possible example, so here it goes:

```
class BaseParameterizedType<T>

fun <U: BaseParameterizedType<*>> getSpecific(clazz: KClass<in U>) : U {
     TODO()
}

fun example(arg: KClass<out BaseParameterizedType<*>>)) {
    getSpecific(arg.innerType)
}
```

Ok, so the code above fails at the 'TODO', but if it wasn't there and if the function returned normally, then it definitely fails with a null pointer exception. I tried hard to figure out what was going wrong, so I turned to the decompiled Java code (from the kotlin bytecode):

```
public static final void example(@NotNull KClass arg) {
  Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(arg, "arg");
  getSpecific(arg.getInnerType());
  throw null;  // <-- The problem
}
```

If I change the function signature of `getSpecific(clz: KClass<in U>) : U` to any of these forms:

1. `getSpecific(clz: KClass<out U>) : U`
2. `getSpecific(clz: KClass<U>) : U`
3. `getSpecific(clz: KClass<in U>) : BaseParameterizedType<*>`

or even the function to `example(arg: KClass<out BaseParameterizedType<*>)` or `example(arg: KClass<BaseParameterizedType<*>>)`, then the generated code is:

```
public static final void example(@NotNull KClass arg) {
  Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(arg, "arg");
  getSpecific(arg.getInnerType());
}
```

Now, let's say at the call-site, I change it to:

```
getSpecific(BaseParameterizedType::class)
```

then this also DOES NOT generate the `throw null` clause. So, I'm guessing this has something to do with kotlin assuming that this cast will always fail or that there is indeterminate information available to make the inference?

So, we know that `arg.innerType` is `KClass<out BaseParameterizedType<*>>` and we use it at a site accepting `KClass<in BaseParameterizedType<*>>`, so why isn't `U` inferred to `BaseParamterizedType<*>>`. That is literally the only type that will ever match.

At the same time, I think just generating a `throw null` statement is unbelievably difficult to debug. The stacktrace would just point to the line where there is `getSpecific` and good luck figuring out where the null pointer exception came from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue regarding the the type inference corner case handling when the inferred type is `Nothing` (and it is in your case):

[image]

The inference behaves in this way because of a coercion attempt for the projections `KClass<in U>` and `KClass<out BaseParameterizedType<*>>`.

Basically, an `out`-projected type at the same time means `in Nothing` (because the actual type argument can be any of the subtypes, and nothing can be safely passed *in*). So, to match `KClass<out BaseParameterizedType<*>>` with `KClass<in U>` the compiler chooses `U := Nothing`, implying that the function call returns `Nothing` as well.

<sup>Remark: a `Foo<out Any>` projection cannot match `Foo<in T>` with `T := Any`, because the actual type argument of the value passed for `Foo<out Any>` can be, for example, `Int`. Then, if `Foo<T>` accepts `T` in some of its functions, allowing the aforementioned match will also allow you to pass `Any` instances to where `Foo<Int>` does not expect them. Actually, `in Nothing` becomes the only way to match them, because of the unknown nature of the `out`-projected type.</sup>

After that, for a `Nothing`-returning function call, the compiler inserts that `throw null` bytecode to make sure the execution does not proceed (evaluating a `Nothing`-typed expression [is supposed to never finish correctly](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html#the-nothing-type)).

See the issues: [KT-20849](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20849), [KT-18789](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18789)

Comment: Did this issue surface recently? Because this is part of the code that was working perfectly for me, and it broke only recently. I am sorry I won't be able to pin-point the exact kotlin version where it started to break because we keep on updating the version and this is something that unfortunately not covered by our test-cases and is a rarely-reached piece of code. So it is difficult to ascertain when exactly it started breaking.

Answer (score 1):

Just as @hotkey mentioned, `out` means `in Nothing` and `Nothing` will throw null.So I do some tests like this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    tryToReturnNothing()
}

fun tryToReturnNothing(): Nothing{
    TODO()
}
```

Generate ->

```
   public static final void main(@NotNull String[] args) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(args, "args");
      tryToReturnNothing();
      throw null;  // here
   }

   @NotNull
   public static final Void tryToReturnNothing() {
      throw (Throwable)(new NotImplementedError((String)null, 1, (DefaultConstructorMarker)null));
   }
```

Considering the type of `null` is `Nothing?`, we can return `Nothing?` instead of `Nothing`. So I change `U` into `U?`, and then the `throw null` clause disappear:

```
fun <U: BaseParameterizedType<*>> getSpecific(clazz: KClass<in U>) : U? { // see here: change U to U?
    TODO()
}

fun example(arg: KClass<out BaseParameterizedType<*>>) {
    getSpecific(arg)
}
```

Generate ->

```
   @Nullable
   public static final BaseParameterizedType getSpecific(@NotNull KClass clazz) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(clazz, "clazz");
      throw (Throwable)(new NotImplementedError((String)null, 1, (DefaultConstructorMarker)null));
   }

   public static final void example(@NotNull KClass arg) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(arg, "arg");
      getSpecific(arg);
   }
```